# How to convert or view Numbers spreadsheet so it can be used in Raspberry?

Tags: macos

How i can read (or convert to some linux format) Mac Numbers spreadsheet file in Raspberry Pi OS?

I cant use any online services.

I can't figure out how to read/convert it in LibreOffice.

File>Wizards>Document Converter only accepts excel files.

I have LibreOffice 6.1.5.2 installed in my Raspberry Pi OS and it's not latest LibreOffice. Not sure is it possible/smart to install latest version.

Comment: Convert it to a supported format such as LibreOffice. Or better still use LibreOffice on your Mac.

Comment: Note that LibreOffice can read most Numbers documents.

Answer (score 0):

In Numbers, save your spreadsheet in Excel file format by clicking File > Export to..., then choose to save it as Excel file format.